# With or without WHERE clause in SQL performance

Tags: sql, performance

Sorry for this newbie question.

I want to query a table with 10 million rows. However, there are historical data that I might not need. In view of lessening the load on the server during data extraction process, would implementing a WHERE clause in the query help? For instance, I could pull only 2015 to 2016 data instead of 2007 to 2016 data.

Or should I just pull the entire data table without a WHERE clause?

Thank you!

Comment: Where should help as long as you have the correct indexes for the where columns.

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Feel free to add the tag back for the database you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`WHERE` would obviously be helpful, because it reduces the number of rows being returned from the database to the application.  Instead of 10 million rows, you will get a smaller number.  This is usually a performance win.

Given that you want to pull complete years of data, the `WHERE` clause may not use an index.  Technically, this is because the selectivity of the condition is too low -- that is, too many rows are returned.  One exception is if the date/year column is a clustered index.

However, not using an index is not relevant, because the volume of data being returned should be a fraction of the total data when your query has the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I suggested to constrain the date to a usable period however my peers said that using WHERE clause will not lighten the load on the server since it will still scan the entire table. 

I was unsure and slightly unconvinced, which is why I asked. Thanks again!